# Overlay div not showing background color

Tags: html, css

I have two div. One contains the navbar and the other is the first section of the site. Both have background images and content. The background of the navbar isn't showing while the content is there. I wanted the navbar to be on top of the section and that is why I have z-index:2. The thing is even if I remove that, the background-color doesn't appear.
I inspected it every way but whatever I do it is simply not showing.

This is the navbar css:

```
#section{
height: 70px;
z-index: 2;
padding-left: 10%;
padding-right: 10%;
clear: both;
max-width: 100%;
background-color: black;

   }
```

This is the section css:

```
    #section-1{

background: url(Images/1.jpg);
max-width: 100%;
padding-top:14%;
padding-bottom: 7%;
color:white;
height:710px;
margin-top:-70px;


    }
```

Here is the HtmL:

```
       <div id="section"> <!-- navigation bar -->
    <div class="navbar" id="nav">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>

 </div>
```

```
  <div id="section-1"> <!-- first -->

     <div class="row"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML as well?

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index only works on positioned elements, so giving your elements a position of relative should make it work.

As of:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: It worked, but if I want the navbar to be fixed then how do I do it? I was planning to use position:fixed for that.

Comment: You can still used position fixed, it is just that the section-1 would need to have a margin top to push it down.

Answer (score 1):

probably do to you not using positions.

```css
#section {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#section-1 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <div id="section-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the element on which you are setting z-index property has its position property set to static. z-index requires the element's position set to anything except static - which is the default.

take a look here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=control

Answer (score 1):

Your `section-1` is a child of `section`. Children will always be *above* their parents. A z-index (which BTW is only active/valid on positioned elements) won't ever change that.

```css
#section {
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#section-1 {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300x200/eb6);
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 14%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  color: white;
  height: 710px;
  margin-top: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <!-- navigation bar -->
  <div class="navbar" id="nav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>

  </div>

  <div id="section-1">
    <!-- first -->

    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```